# Best approach to have 'at location since' a time?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-location

I am trying to display the time the user arrived at the current location in a label, for example, as 'Since 09:41'.
I have tried to achieve this in various ways using Core Location:

- Using the arrivalDate from CLVisit
- Updating it with the current time when the location updates in didUpdateLocations with a distanceFilter
- Updating it with the current time when the user exits a placemark region in didExitRegion.

However, I am wondering if anybody could suggest a better way to do this as I have found difficulties with the above methods. Using CLVisit was too slow, and the other two updated the time even if the user was still in the same area.

I am very new to Swift so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve, can you post your code?